# KDB: Preserve Leading Zeros When Saving Data to CSV?

Tags: excel, csv, formatting, kdb

I'm trying to export data from KDB to a csv file. Unfortunately, when I do this, the leading zeros disappear. For example, 0355 becomes 355.

Is there a hack of sorts that I can use to get around this issue?

Comment: This is saving down straight from KDB to csv file. So I'd rather not use excel as an intermediary. I should also add that the the column type in the KDB table is a symbol not a number

Comment: Are you viewing the csv files via excel?

Comment: It's being viewed on Excel

Comment: Can you view the raw csv in notepad? The zeros may be present there but absent when viewed in excel as it formats the column as a number.

Comment: The zeros are present when viewing from Notepad. The issue is that the user will be viewing this from Excel and the values are to be copy and pasted to his/her own proprietary database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your issue may be in the process of opening the CSV with excel. The prevailing 0's are still present until viewed in excel.

If you are wanting to view the data in excel one option would be to first string the data and then add a prevailing ' in kdb. For example:

```
q)table: flip `a`b`c!(`001`002`003; 123; 10 12 12)
q)update a:("'",'string a) from table
a      b   c
-------------
"'001" 123 10
"'002" 123 12
"'003" 123 12
```

This effectively acts as a indicator stating "this is text", thus the 0 will be retained. The ' will not be visible in the cells unless you edit a specific cell, as a result it is useful for displaying these symbols. Other than this I think your best option would be to just change the column type settings in excel.

Comment: Doing this now force a " ' " to appear before each value in a cell. i.e. '2018.

Answer (score 2):

If your .csv file contains the leading 0's when opened in notepad, then the problem is likely that Excel is misinterpreting the value as a number since when kdb+ exports symbols to a csv file it does without wrapping the value in quotation marks.

To get around this open Excel and click on the 'Data' ribbon and then 'From Text' to import your csv using the Import Wizard. Once you have selected your csv, the wizard will open and you can set the delimeter as comma.

You will then be able to choose the data types for each column, and setting the column with the leading 0's as text format will make them appear correctly.